# Refine.dev Fetching multiple records from different tables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, supabase, refinejs

How do you deal with fetching multiple records from two or more tables from the API using the [useTable](https://refine.dev/docs/data/hooks/use-table/) hook instead of [useMany](https://refine.dev/docs/data/hooks/use-many/)? Under the hood, useTable uses [useList](https://refine.dev/docs/data/hooks/use-list/).   Let's say I have customers and order tables from the providers. Is there a way to tell the useTable to get records from that two tables?

```js
type Customers = {
  id: number;
  customer_name: string;
  customer_contact: string;
};

type ServiceType = "Wash" | "Dry" | "Fold" | "Full";
type ServiceStatus = "Undone" | "Washing" | "Drying" | "Folding" | "Done";

type Orders = {
  id: number;
  customerId: number;
  orderDate: Date;
  orderLoad: number;
  orderWeight: number;
  serviceType: ServiceType;
  orderSoap: number;
  orderFabcon: number;
  orderBleach: number;
  orderNote: string;
  orderStatus: ServiceStatus;
  orderIsClaimed: boolean;
  inventoryId: number | null;
  payableId: number | null;
};


const {
    refineCore: {
      tableQueryResult: { data: orders },
    },
    previousPage,
    nextPage,
    getCanPreviousPage,
    getCanNextPage,
    getHeaderGroups,
    getRowModel,
    getColumn,
    getAllColumns,
  } = useTable({
    columns,
    onSortingChange: setSorting,
    onColumnFiltersChange: setColumnFilters,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    getPaginationRowModel: getPaginationRowModel(),
    getSortedRowModel: getSortedRowModel(),
    getFilteredRowModel: getFilteredRowModel(),
    onColumnVisibilityChange: setColumnVisibility,
    onRowSelectionChange: setRowSelection,
    state: {
      sorting,
      columnFilters,
      columnVisibility,
      rowSelection,
    },
  });
```

Here's the provider:

```js
<Refine
    dataProvider={dataProvider(supabaseClient)}
    liveProvider={liveProvider(supabaseClient)}
    authProvider={authProvider}
    routerProvider={routerBindings}
    resources={[
      {
        name: "orders",
        list: "/orders",
        create: "/orders/create",
        edit: "/orders/edit/:id",
        show: "/orders/show/:id",
        meta: {
          canDelete: true,
        },
      },
      {
        name: "customers",
        list: "/customers",
        create: "/customers/create",
        edit: "/customers/edit/:id",
        show: "/customers/show/:id",
        meta: {
          canDelete: true,
        },
      },
      {
        name: "inventory",
        list: "/inventory",
        show: "/inventory/show/:id",
        meta: {
          canDelete: true,
        },
      },
    ]}
    options={{
      syncWithLocation: true,
      warnWhenUnsavedChanges: true,
      useNewQueryKeys: true,
      projectId: "GmM62Q-BMA8wv-2ddnfk",
    }}
  >
</Refine>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`useTable` makes a request to single endpoint, building filter, pagination, sorter parameters for you. Logically, a table should include records from a single endpoint.

Although it's not clear from the question, you may want to show customer information (name, email) under a table column of orders. Handling that depends on your API.

For example, if you are using GraphQL, you can do something like this:

```
query OrdersTable($params: OrderQueryParams) {
  orders(params: $params) {
    id
    orderDate
    customer { id email name }
  }
}
```

Or if your REST API supports something like "include":

`https://api.example.com/orders&include=customer`

If your API doesn't support any of these, you will need to extract `customerIds` from the `useTable` response and fetch customers with `useMany` hook.

https://refine.dev/docs/data/hooks/use-many/#ids-